# Replace placeholder text in embedded javascript code

Tags: jquery, html

I have a pop-up window (it's a mailchimp singup pop-up) and there is placeholder text I would like to replace. This could theoretically be done with jquery text function, but the problem is the pop up is embeded to the site with this code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//downloads.mailchimp.com/js/signup-forms/popup/embed.js" data-dojo-config="usePlainJson: true, isDebug: false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">require(["mojo/signup-forms/Loader"], function(L) { L.start({"baseUrl":"mc.us15.list-manage.com","uuid":"9f9db56c3e8da76e10b1d9c12","lid":"9aabbe0a76"}) })</script>
```

This means there's no actual markup in the code to target and I'm not sure jquery can work this way. Code that is generated is

```
<input type="email" name="EMAIL" value="" id="mc-EMAIL" placeholder="Enter your email">
```

and I need to replace the placeholder text for something else.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Try this , If you just want to change the placeholder you can write following JQuery code

```
$("#mc-EMAIL").attr("placeholder","Your Placeholder.... ");
```